# Not able to click on the ImageButton

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

Not able to click on the element using Espresso. The code is

```
onView(withId(R.id.nav_btn_menu)).perform(click());
```

I want to click on the above ImageButton but it is throwing the error as

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 727, 1207 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'with id: com.xyz.p2p.app:id/nav_btn_menu'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:82)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:79)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:173)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:114)
at com.xyz.p2p.app.Test8_OrgRegisterNumberActivityTest.test1_onCreate_Serviceno(Test8_OrgRegisterNumberActivityTest.java:214)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1867)
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'click (after 3 attempts)' on view 'unknown'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:82)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendDown(MotionEvents.java:119)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:168)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:31)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:47)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:136)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:248)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:63)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:153)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
```

Note:  Other buttons on the same page and in the same row can be clicked. Actually, there are two buttons whose visibility toggle. Other button at the same place is also showing the same error for its element.

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: The code is mentioned above. Actually, in my app, there is a page where the bottom includes 3 different buttons which are in a row. Out of them, 2 buttons can be clicked but 3rd button which has the ID as above cannot be clicked despite being on the same page and in a row .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it was an ImageView not an ImageButton. I was like you able to test clicks on views similar, just not one button.  The only difference was that in the imageView I was rotating the image,  when I removed the rotation it worked

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:src="@drawable/back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/top_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/top_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This part was causing the problem:
        android:rotation="180"